# How to store and retrieve values from a list in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, python-3.7, dynamodb-queries

I have a python function which does the steps listed in 'Current Implementation' section. I am currently working on porting the code to AWS and I intend to use AWS lambda with Python3. In the future implementation I want to move away from using file system. I also wanted to find a more efficient way to check whether a TimeStamp exist in the log without having to loop through each line. I was thinking of using DynamoDB.

- Given my data is just an array as given below, does it make sense to have it in a DynamoDB table?
- How can I structure the table and retrieve the last value efficiently in this case?
- Please recommend any other scalable method I can use for this, if available.

+--------------+

|  1574901524  |

|  1574900179  |

|  1574898834  |

|  1574897489  |

|  1574892109  |

+--------------+

## Current Implementation

1. Read a file with a list of values (each value separated by newline).
2. If the timestamp doesn't exist, then perform some action.

```
datafile = file('log.txt')
for line in datafile:
    if str(timestamp) in line:
        # do nothing
    else:
        #do something
```

3. Write the new timestamp to the file.

```
logentry = str(timestamp)+"\n"
with open("log.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(logentry)
```

Comment: You can use dynamodb this way if speed is really an issue for you. You will then have timestamp as your primary key and can simply query it to check if value exists. It is pretty straightforward so you can go through the boto3 dynamodb docs and give it a try.

Comment: Did the same and it seems yo work. Is that the best approach possible in this case?